# Change opacity of lighten composition layer

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using the command below to overlay an image (`../esrgan/{1}`) with another image (`{1}`) that I scale to 400% and then apply lighten composition to.

`parallel --bar --xapply convert {1} -filter Lanczos -resize 400% ../esrgan/{1} +swap -compose Lighten -composite ../esrgan/{1} ::: *.png`

On top of that, I also want to set the opacity of the top layer (`{1}`) to 75%. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your complete syntax there, but within the part that is appears to be an ImageMagick command, right after the "-resize" and before reading in the second image, add this to the code...

```
... -channel A -evaluate set 75% +channel ...
```

That tells the command to only use the alpha channel for the following operation(s). The "-evaluate" operation sets the alpha channel to a value of 75%. Then the "+channel" with the plus "+" ends that special setting and continues with the command.

If the first input file doesn't have an alpha channel, you can add "-alpha set" to make sure the image has an alpha channel before changing the value.

Comment: Nice answer! The other syntax is **GNU Parallel**,  btw. It just means apply the `convert` in parallel to all images named after the `:::`